# I'm having an issue when adding a slider in a menuItem where the tab will stop showing the desired charts they once did

Tags: r, shiny

The Shiny dashboard fails to show data it once did when a slider input is added 
The code runs perfectly if I remove menuSubItem from the histogram menu item when its added however it only shows me the linegraphs even when on the histogram menu item.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
longdata1 <- read.csv("longdata1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar( 
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Histograms", tabName = "Histograms", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
                     menuSubItem(icon=NULL, 
                                 sliderInput("bars",
                                             "Number of Bars",
                                             min = 3,
                                             max = 40,
                                             value = 10) )

        ),

       menuItem("Linegraphs",tabName = "Linegraphs", icon = icon("line-chart")),



       varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", longdata1),
       sliderInput("bars",
                   "Number of Bars:",
                   min = 3,
                   max = 40,
                   value = 10)



       )


    ),
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

         tabItem(tabName = "Histograms",
                h2(plotOutput("dist3Plot"),plotOutput("dist4Plot"))

        ),

        tabItem(tabName = "Linegraphs",
                h2( plotOutput("dist10Plot"))
        )
    )
),
skin = "black"
)
```

Comment: Please try give us a minimal reproducible example to test with.

Comment: this is about as minimal as you can get..

Comment: But it's not reproducible. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Other people don't have access to "longdata1.csv" and it would be beneficial for anyone trying to help if they can just run a simple app directly from your code. That is the best way to test your example and not make their own possibly different assumptions leading to different results. Also a min reprex narrows down your problem to its most basic level and sometimes helps you solve it yourself.